# copy a list of files+directories with shutil with Python 3.XX

Tags: python, list, file, directory, copy

I have to copy the files + folders from a local directory to a distant one (LAN network)

To be more efficient, I want to copy only the files and directories who doesn't exist already in the distant directory.

for that, I tried this :

get a list of the missing elements:

```
lst_difference_cible = sorted(set.difference(set(localfiles), set(distfiles)))
```

then copy the elements of this list to a temp folder(_SOURCE_TEMP)

```
for files in lst_difference_cible:
   shutil.copy2(files, _SOURCE_TEMP)
```

then use pysftp to upload the content of the temp folder to the distant one

```
with pysftp.Connection(host=_RMTHOST, username=_USR, password=_DESTPASS) as sftp:
    sftp.put_r(_SOURCE_TEMP, _DEST)
```

It's working for the files, but not for the directories. I tried shutil.copytree, and many others solutions, but I always get errors "path expected, not list"

Here is the part of my script:

```
# création de liste récursive de fichiers locaux
localfiles = os.listdir(_SOURCE)

print("fichiers sur répertoire source: \n ")
for f in localfiles:
    print(f)

#connexion pour listing fichiers présents répertoire distant
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

# importation auto de clé de connexion avec le client
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy( paramiko.AutoAddPolicy() )
ssh.connect(_RMTHOST, username=_USR, password=_DESTPASS)

ftp = ssh.open_sftp()
distfiles = ftp.listdir(_DEST)
print("fichiers sur répertoire de destination: \n")
for f in distfiles:
    print(f)

ssh.close()
ftp.close()


# list of the files/folders not existing in dist folder
lst_difference_cible = sorted(set.difference(set(localfiles), set(distfiles)))


if lst_difference_cible:

    print("Dossiers/fichiers non présents dans le répertoire de destination " + _DEST )
    print(lst_difference_cible)

# création du répertoire temporaire pour copie
_SOURCE_TEMP = (_SOURCE + "temp")

if not os.path.exists(_SOURCE_TEMP):
    os.makedirs(_SOURCE_TEMP, exist_ok=True)

#copie des fichiers absents du répertoire distant sur le dossier temporaire pour transfert

os.chdir(_SOURCE)

#for directory in lst_difference_cible:
   #shutil.copytree(directory, _SOURCE_TEMP, ignore=ignore_fonction)

for files in lst_difference_cible:
   shutil.copy2(files, _SOURCE_TEMP)

#copie des fichiers dans le répertoire distant

with pysftp.Connection(host=_RMTHOST, username=_USR, password=_DESTPASS) as sftp:
    sftp.put_r(_SOURCE_TEMP, _DEST)

    sftp.close()
```

I have to say that I'm a very early beginner, and I apologise for the poor quality of my script, but I really try my best, and I tried many days to solve my problem, but I'm stuck.

Could you please help me in any way ?

Comment: Sorry I know next to nothing about FTP and I can't test this part of your code. Did you manage to create folders on server this way? Just a folder. Just to be sure. Since the rest part of this task looks rather trivial for me.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the question more precisely and @Yuri Khristich helped me a lot, this is the link to the solution on SO :
[Compare two lists of filenames + size+ modification time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68146545/compare-two-lists-of-filenames-size-modification-time)