# Compare two lists of filenames + size+ modification time

Tags: python, list, file, difference

For a student project, I build a script to copy to a distant repertory only the "new" files.
I'm able to find the files not present in the distant folder and copy it, it's working.
Now, I try to copy the files with the same name, but with a different size or modification date.

I'm able to create a list of local files with all the needed information:

```
localfilestime = os.scandir(_SOURCE)

print("fichiers sur répertoire source: \n ")

for file in localfilestime:

    localfilestime = (file.stat().st_size, file.stat().st_mtime, file.name)
    print (localfilestime)
```

and the same on the distant one:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy( paramiko.AutoAddPolicy() )
ssh.connect(_RMTHOST, username=_USR, password=_DESTPASS)

ftp = ssh.open_sftp()
distfilestime = ftp.listdir_attr(_DEST)

print("fichiers sur répertoire de destination: \n")
for f in distfilestime:
    distfilestime =(f.st_size,f.st_mtime, f.filename)
    print (distfilestime)
```

I get two sorted lists, but I have two problems:

```
fichiers sur répertoire source: 
 
(915, 1622736305.82416, '20_060_12C_24T_3800_AMD_Ryzen_9_3900X_12_Core_Processor_64_Bit.txt')
(9602, 1624743218.308332, 'blabla.txt')
(143897, 1583941480.0, 'Projet4_configuration_navigateur_proxy01.jpg')
(0, 1624520128.9788647, 'testcopie.txt')
**********************************************************************************************************

fichiers sur répertoire de destination: 

(915, 1622736305, '20_060_12C_24T_3800_AMD_Ryzen_9_3900X_12_Core_Processor_64_Bit.txt')
(37, 1624738406, 'blabla.txt')
(143897, 1583941480, 'Projet4_configuration_navigateur_proxy01.jpg')
(0, 1624520128, 'testcopie.txt')
```

1. the mtime in the local list return a float, and not in the distant one, and I think it will be impossible to compare these numbers properly.
2. I can't find a working solution to compare these lists of files, I tried many solutions, and the "less worst":

   ```py
   def get_difference(list_a, list_b):
       return set(list_a) - set(list_b)


   list_a = localfilestime
   list_b = distfilestime

   non_match = list(get_difference(list_a, list_b))
   print("No match elements: ", set(non_match))
   ```

   return only a non modified file mtime, and not the files with a different size like "blabla.txt":

   ```
   No match elements:  {1624520128.9788647}
   ```

I'm sure I make a mistake somewhere, maybe my method is not good. Could someone help me with this question?

EDIT: this is the entire script, used on Win10 between 2 lan servers
(1 physical, 1 on Virtualbox on private share network) the script call a configuration file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
import socket
import paramiko
import pysftp
import shutil




# importation des variables globales
from configuration import _USR, _RMTHOST, _DESTPASS, _PORT, _SOURCE, _DEST, _EXCLUSION,  _TIMEDATE, _OUTPUT

#Définition de la variable globale nécessaire à la création du dussier temporaire de copie
_SOURCE_TEMP = (_SOURCE + "temp")

#effacer dossier temporaire en cas d'erreur du script précédent
if os.path.exists(_SOURCE_TEMP):
    shutil.rmtree(_SOURCE_TEMP)


# énoncé du script

print("\ncopie miroir du dossier: " + _SOURCE + "  vers:" + _RMTHOST +(": ") + _DEST)

print("\n**********************************************************************************************************\n")

# vérifier présence du fichier de configuration
try:
    with open('configuration.py'):
        pass
        print("le fichier de configuration est présent et valide")
except IOError:
    sys.exit("Erreur: le fichier de configuration n’est pas present, annulation du backup")

print("\n**********************************************************************************************************\n")


# Vérifier l'accès au fichier source

if os.path.exists(_SOURCE):
    print("le dossier source: ", _SOURCE, "est valide et accessible \n \n")
else:
    print("le dossier source: ", _SOURCE, "n\’est pas valide/existant, annulation du backup \n \n")
    sys.exit()

print("**********************************************************************************************************\n")
# test de connexion vers le serveur distant

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    try:
        s.connect((_RMTHOST, _PORT))
        s.sendall(b'Hello, world')
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print('communication réussie avec le serveur ' + _RMTHOST, repr(data) + ('\n \n'))

    except Exception as ex:
        print(
            "impossible de se connecter au serveur, vérifiez vos identifiants\n \n************************ \n\nannulation de la sauvegarde")
        sys.exit()

print("**********************************************************************************************************\n")

# création de liste de fichiers locaux

localfilestime = os.scandir(_SOURCE)


print("fichiers sur répertoire source: \n ")

for f in localfilestime:

    localfilestime = (f.stat().st_size, f.stat().st_mtime, f.name)

    print (localfilestime)



print("**********************************************************************************************************\n")

#connexion pour listing fichiers présents répertoire distant
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

# importation auto de clé de connexion avec le client
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy( paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(_RMTHOST, username=_USR, password=_DESTPASS)

ftp = ssh.open_sftp()

distfilestime = ftp.listdir_attr(_DEST)

print("fichiers sur répertoire de destination: \n")
for f in distfilestime:
    distfilestime =(f.st_size,f.st_mtime, f.filename)
    print (distfilestime)


#comparaison éléments

loc_files = {}
for f in localfilestime:
    size = f.stat().st_size
    time = int(f.stat().st_mtime)
    name = f.name
    loc_files[(size, time, name)] = f

srv_files = {}
for f in distfilestime:
    size = f.st_size
    time = f.st_mtime
    name = f.filename
    srv_files[(size, time, name)] = f


# get lists of unique files based on keys (size,time,name) of these dicts

loc_uniq = [ loc_files[x] for x in loc_files if x not in srv_files ]
srv_uniq = [ srv_files[x] for x in srv_files if x not in loc_files ]

print(loc_uniq)

print("\n**********************************************************************************************************\n")

# création du répertoire temporaire pour copie
_SOURCE_TEMP = (_SOURCE + "temp")

if not os.path.exists(_SOURCE_TEMP):
    os.makedirs(_SOURCE_TEMP, exist_ok=True)

#clôture de la connexion avec le serveur distant
ssh.close()
ftp.close()

#copie des fichiers absents du répertoire distant sur le dossier temporaire pour transfert

os.chdir(_SOURCE)

for files in loc_uniq:
    shutil.copy2(files, _SOURCE_TEMP)

#retirer fichiers à exclure
os.chdir(_SOURCE_TEMP)
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]

for f in files:
    if f.endswith(_EXCLUSION):
        print(f, "ne sera pas copié selon la liste d'exclusion")
        os.remove(f)

os.chdir(_SOURCE)

print("\n**********************************************************************************************************\n")

#copie des fichiers dans le répertoire distant

with pysftp.Connection(host=_RMTHOST, username=_USR, password=_DESTPASS) as sftp:
    sftp.put(_SOURCE_TEMP, _DEST, preserve_mtime=True)

    sftp.close()

if os.path.exists(_SOURCE_TEMP):
    shutil.rmtree(_SOURCE_TEMP)
```

the configuration file:

```
import time

_EXCLUSION = '.ini'
_SOURCE = "C:\\Users\\XXX\\testp6\\"
_OUTPUT = _SOURCE + time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d-%Hh%Mmin%Ss')
_TIMEDATE = time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d-%Hh%Mmin%Ss')
_DEST = "C:\\Users\\XXXx\\test_distant_p6\\"
_USR = 'XXX'
_RMTHOST ='192.168.56.103'
_DESTPASS='XXX'
_PORT=22
```

and the actual return:

```
copie miroir du dossier: C:\Users\Jerem\testp6\  vers:192.168.56.103: C:\Users\turmix\test_distant_p6\

**********************************************************************************************************

le fichier de configuration est présent et valide

**********************************************************************************************************

le dossier source:  C:\Users\Jerem\testp6\ est valide et accessible 
 

**********************************************************************************************************

communication réussie avec le serveur 192.168.56.103 b'SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1\r\n'
 

**********************************************************************************************************

fichiers sur répertoire source: 
 
(915, 1622736305.82416, '20_060_12C_24T_3800_AMD_Ryzen_9_3900X_12_Core_Processor_64_Bit.txt')
(9602, 1624743218.308332, 'blabla.txt')
(46, 1624736892.7385924, 'desktop.ini')
(143897, 1583941480.0, 'Projet4_Jeremie_Voita_configuration_navigateur_proxy01.jpg')
(0, 1624520128.9788647, 'testcopie.txt')
**********************************************************************************************************

fichiers sur répertoire de destination: 

(915, 1622736305, '20_060_12C_24T_3800_AMD_Ryzen_9_3900X_12_Core_Processor_64_Bit.txt')
(37, 1624738406, 'blabla.txt')
(143897, 1583941480, 'Projet4_Jeremie_Voita_configuration_navigateur_proxy01.jpg')
(0, 1624520128, 'testcopie.txt')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jerem\OneDrive\P6\pythonP6\dernierendate.py", line 118, in <module>
    size = f.stat().st_size
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'stat'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: 1. Why don't you run the python command directly using SSH? You connect through SSH and then you call a SFTP function to retrieve the stats, sounds a bit overkill.
2. Suggestion on how to compare it: You can use a dictionary, whereas the Key will be the filename, and each key might be another dictionary based on file size. Thus a Miss means there is a difference in files or they don't exist. Let me know if you can move forward with the aforementioned suggestions

Comment: I may have a large list of files in the directories, and I thought it will be slower through SSh? Also, I tried this solution , but I can't use the basic comparing modules with a distant repertory, it returns always errors.. Of course I think some solutions are existing, but i'm beginner and I tried to kept my script as simple as possible. I will make some research about dictionary, thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

It can be done many ways. For example this way:

```
localfilestime = [
    (915, 1622736305.82416, '20_060_12C_24T_3800_AMD_Ryzen_9_3900X_12_Core_Processor_64_Bit.txt'),
    (9602, 1624743218.308332, 'blabla.txt'),
    (143897, 1583941480.0, 'Projet4_configuration_navigateur_proxy01.jpg'),
    (0, 1624520128.9788647, 'testcopie.txt'),
]

distfilestime = [
    (915, 1622736305, '20_060_12C_24T_3800_AMD_Ryzen_9_3900X_12_Core_Processor_64_Bit.txt'),
    (37, 1624738406, 'blabla.txt'),
    (143897, 1583941480, 'Projet4_configuration_navigateur_proxy01.jpg'),
    (0, 1624520128, 'testcopie.txt'),
]

# convert float dates into integer dates
localfilestime = [(size, int(date), name) for (size, date, name) in localfilestime]

# convert every element of the lists into a { key:value }
localfilestime = { str(x):x for x in localfilestime }
distfilestime  = { str(x):x for x in distfilestime  }

# get unique values from the lists
localfilestime_uniques = { localfilestime[x] for x in localfilestime if x not in distfilestime  }
distfilestime_uniques  = { distfilestime[x]  for x in distfilestime  if x not in localfilestime }

print(localfilestime_uniques) # {(9602, 1624743218, 'blabla.txt')}
print(distfilestime_uniques)  # {(37, 1624738406, 'blabla.txt')}
```

---

**Update**

Probably you need this:

```
# make the dicts { (size, time, name) : file }

loc_files = {}
for f in localfilestime:
    size = f.stat().st_size
    time = int(f.stat().st_mtime)
    name = f.name
    loc_files[(size, time, name)] = f

srv_files = {}
for f in distfilestime:
    size = f.st_size
    time = f.st_mtime
    name = f.filename
    srv_files[(size, time, name)] = f


# get lists of unique files based on keys (size,time,name) of these dicts

loc_uniq = [ loc_files[x] for x in loc_files if x not in srv_files ]
srv_uniq = [ srv_files[x] for x in srv_files if x not in loc_files ]
```

Teoreticaly it should work it should give you two lists with unique files (based on a size, time, name). But I can't test it properly since I have no the FTP server with your files.

---

I've tested the local part of the code on Windows and Mac and this part works just fine:

```
import os
from pprint import pprint

localfilestime = os.scandir(r"c:\\temp")

loc_files = {}
for f in localfilestime:
    size = f.stat().st_size
    time = int(f.stat().st_mtime)
    name = f.name
    loc_files[(size, time, name)] = f

pprint(loc_files)
```

Sample of output:

```
{(0, 1622330493, 'test - Copy.txt'): <DirEntry 'test - Copy.txt'>,
 (0, 1622330493, 'test.txt'): <DirEntry 'test.txt'>,
 (124, 1622332489, 'test.zip'): <DirEntry 'test.zip'>,
 (267, 1624901883, 'loc_files.py'): <DirEntry 'loc_files.py'>}
```

Comment: Great, thank you for your answer, I will try it asap, it seems exactly what i needed. There is so much possibilities, for a beginner it's very hard to not get lost and learn step by step.

Comment: My sample above is just an example how you can compare given lists of tuples (size, time, name). But it seems your actual lists are wired a little bit differently. So, you have these two lists with files (tuples with the many file properties). And you need to compare them by some of these properties (size, time, name) and get the list of different files (list of the tulips with many file properties)?

Comment: Exactly! Then I would like to copy the newer/heavyer files to the distant repertory, with "1" added to the name, for exemple. I think I know how to rename files, but it's actually useless. I can add the entire script to my initial question if it's useful. Thank you again for taking time to help me

Comment: #facepalm I forgot to remove the comma at the end of this line `size = f.stat().st_size,` <-- here. Try it without the comma. This is exactly why it's not a good idea to post a code without testing

Comment: I think the problem is maybe that i use os.scandir(source) and it don't manage lists like ftp.listdir_attr?

Comment: I don't know. I can't test FTP part of the code, but I just tested the local part of the code and it works fine. I'm getting `loc_files` dictionary with sizes, times, etc. `os.scandir()` and `size = f.stat().st_size` work with no problem. I tested it on macOS. I'll try it on Windows asap. Did your code in OP work fine for you yesterday on the same folder and files? Because I didn't change it, I сopied it and pasted in my code as is, as you can see (except that stupid typo)

Comment: I've tested it on Windows 10 and it works fine as well. There is nothing to be broken in this little snippet. As for your error it's #facepalmstrikesback. You're using the module `time` and trying to use the variable `time` in the same code, which is a not exactly brilliant idea.

Comment: ... It's not a facepalm... it's a footpalm for me!!!!!! It's working perfectly!! Sorry for the large amount of "!" but I spent 1 week to make just this part of the script, and I was completly stuck. Then YOU made it. I would llike to thank you very much, for your tenacity and disponibility, you made my day!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Yuri Khristich I have a solution perfectly working :

use:

```
import os
import sys
import socket
import paramiko
import pysftp
import shutil
from pprint import pprint

#for local files

localfilestime = os.scandir(r"c:\\temp")

loc_files = {}
for f in localfilestime:
    size = f.stat().st_size
    time = int(f.stat().st_mtime)
    name = f.name
    loc_files[(size, time, name)] = f

print("fichiers sur répertoire source: \n ")
pprint(loc_files)

#for distant files

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

# importation auto de clé de connexion avec le client
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy( paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(_RMTHOST, username=_USR, password=_DESTPASS)

ftp = ssh.open_sftp()

distfilestime = ftp.listdir_attr(_DEST)

dst_files = {}
for f in distfilestime:
    size = f.st_size
    time = f.st_mtime
    name = f.filename
    dst_files[(size, time, name)] = f

print("fichiers sur répertoire de destination: \n")
pprint(dst_files)

#clôture de la connexion avec le serveur distant
ssh.close()
ftp.close()

#create a list of files not present/differents(name, size, modification date) on the distant server:

loc_uniq = [ loc_files[x] for x in loc_files if x not in dst_files ]

#create a temp folder to copy the different files

_SOURCE_TEMP = (_SOURCE + "temp")

if not os.path.exists(_SOURCE_TEMP):
    os.makedirs(_SOURCE_TEMP, exist_ok=True)


#copy the files

for files in loc_uniq:
    shutil.copy2(files, _SOURCE_TEMP)

#if you want to exclude some files from the copy list

os.chdir(_SOURCE_TEMP)
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]

for f in files:
    if f.endswith(_EXCLUSION):
        print(f, "ne sera pas copié selon la liste d'exclusion")
        os.remove(f)

#copy the files from the temp repertory to the distant 

with pysftp.Connection(host=_RMTHOST, username=_USR, password=_DESTPASS) as sftp:
    sftp.put_r(_SOURCE_TEMP, _DEST, preserve_mtime=True)

    sftp.close()
```

this part of script is perfectly working on Win10, and the lists are working also on OSX ( Tested by Yuri ) I first had an error ( in  size = f.stat().st_size, AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'stat') because I imported the "time" module, be aware of that.
Thank you 1000 times for your kind help Yuri!

Comment: My script is finished, I uploaded in Github for sharing, I don't know if it's against the SO rules to post it here so if it's the case, just message me and I will delete this URL: https://github.com/Turmix80/Python-mirror-script